# SSRS Encryption key error after failover

Tags: availability-groups, ssrs

I recently encountered an error after a planned failover of an AG to the secondary node after patching it.  I am on SQL 2016 enterprise.  we have the reportserver in the AG, but after failover I got the below error.

[image: SSRS Encryption Key Error after Failover]

This is a 2 node AG, both participating in scale-out deployment.  on the node that was rebooted the scale-out tab in config manager does not show any of the nodes present, but the other node shows both nodes as joined.

[image: Scale Out Tab]
I have automation to handle the nessesary restart of the SQL agent and SSRS service that needs to happen after a failover to recognize the new primary node, and it works correctly.

As soon as I restore the encryption key to the primary node the issue goes away...  Does anyone know you would need to restore the encryption key after a failover?  I can understand after a migration or something, not i would not think it should be needed after a failover.

Comment: Is the master key on each node the same?

If its the same you should not need to import the SSRS DB key each time.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm looking at the right spot for the master key, but the Symmetric and public key on the keys table are they same on each node.  is that what you mean?  I did see something else that seems odd though.  I looked in the rsreportserver.config file and the installation ID for both nodes is the same.  both nodes have the same installationID that is listed in the keys table for the secondary node.  could this be the problem?  If not, can you explain where I can find the master key you mentioned?  pardon the ignorance, I haven't been asked to look for a master SSRS key before

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/using-database-master-keys-in-sql-server